# floating point values not displaying accurate number of digits c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, math

Having trouble giving the correct digits for my $ output.

every time i plug in for example 8 in the statement i get numbers with 3 digits Ex. 10.9
While i would like it to display $10.90

I just added the setprecision hoping that it will fix the issue, did not work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int Ts;    // holds Ts 
    float Price, Tcost, Total;


    cout << "How many shirts you like ?" << endl;
    cin >> Ts;

    Total = 12 * Ts;

    if ( 5 < Ts && Ts < 10)
        Tcost = (Total - (.10 * Total));
        Price = (Tcost / Ts);
        cout << "he cost per shirt is $" << setprecision(4) << Price << " and the total cost is $" << Tcost << setprecision(4) << endl;




    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the *expected* output as well as the *actual* output. In full.

Comment: Oh and remember that C++ isn't Python. Indentation is nice to have since it makes it easier to read, but it's not relevant to scoping. You're missing a couple of curly-braces `{}`. This is something that every [good beginners book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) (and even bad ones) would have told you.

Comment: StackOverflow would be a more welcoming and useful resource if people spent more time helping the newbies and less time criticizing them over minor details.

Comment: I don't get it. Total = 96, Then Tcost = Total - 9.6, which is 86.4. Price = 86.4/8, which is 10.8. This is somewhat close to your answer (Floating point disrepancies). What are you expecting?

Comment: The code that i get from my professor doesn't have the {} curly-braces if that is what you are talking about @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I'm expecting it to out put 10.80

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner

Comment: I recommend testing against input of 12 to see the bug Some programmer dude brought up about the missing braces.

Comment: If you want more than one statement inside an `if` you need the curly-braces. I suspect the professor expects you to think a little for yourself.

Comment: Yeah i had to reformat my code thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)(Which will set the amount of decimals after the point to be printed as decided by `setprecision(N)`) and [`std::setprecision(2)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) (So that two decimals are printed), and the code should now work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int Ts;    // holds Ts 
    float Price, Tcost, Total;


    cout << "How many shirts you like ?" << endl;
    cin >> Ts;

    Total = 12 * Ts;

    if ( 5 < Ts && Ts < 10)
        Tcost = (Total - (.10 * Total));
        Price = (Tcost / Ts); // The indentation is weird here
                              // but I will leave it as it is
        cout << "he cost per shirt is $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << Price << " and the total cost is $" << Tcost << setprecision(2) << endl;
    return 0;


}
```

The output I get from this is:

```
How many shirts you like ?
8
he cost per shirt is $10.80 and the total cost is $86.40
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried using the fixed and it didnt work before .

Comment: yes it does i took the same format of this and tried to run it in different values and im getting problems where its displaying the cout 4 times with no values

Comment: @BlackHawkD721 Could you give an example of input that isn't working? I tried this will all values from 6-9, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `std::cout.setf(std::ios::showpoint);` then it will work.

Comment: Why would i have to put that in when previously i just kept it as 'cout'  ??

Comment: because std::cout don't show decimal point zero. So u must set the format of cout for show decimal point zero.

Comment: The answer is correct, but not complete, unfortunately, @BlackHawkD721 . [The `setf` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) sets a stream formatting option. [`std::ios::showpoint` is the option set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags), but you may find `cout << "The cost per shirt is $" << showpoint << setprecision(4) << Price << " and the total cost is $" << Tcost << endl;` a little more familiar. You will need to add `#include <ios>`. [Docs on `showpoint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint)